# How to import a namespace defined in index.d.ts

Tags: typescript

Trying to import xmlbuilder to my typescript class by

```js
import { xmlbuilder } from "xmlbuilder/typings/index";
```

I got

> Error:(2, 10) TS2305: Module '../node_modules/xmlbuilder/typings/index"' has no exported member 'xmlbuilder'.

In the index.d.ts (https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/blob/master/typings/index.d.ts),

```js
export = xmlbuilder;

declare namespace xmlbuilder { 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to import a type definition, not the actual type.

You should use the following code:

```js
import xmlbuilder from "xmlbuilder"
```

Type definitions are simply ways to describe to TypeScript how the JavaScript object should look like. This makes possible to files written in JavaScript to be interpreted by TypeScript compiler and compiled JS files written in TypeScript to be used from JS files.

---

As noted in the comments, when modules doesn't have a default export, you should use an *alias*, importing the entire module.

```js
import * as xmlbuilder from "xmlbuilder"
```

This is the equivalent of using `require("xmlbuilder")`.

Comment: I got this
Error:(2, 8) TS1192: '".../node_modules/xmlbuilder/typings/index"' has no default export. when I do import xmlbuilder from 'xmlbuilder';

Comment: `import * as xmlbuilder from 'xmlbuilder'` can be used if the module does not have a default export.

Comment: As @JakeHolzinger said, you should use an **alias** for xmlbuilder, if doesn't have a default export. This will be the same as using `const xmlbuilder = require("xmlbuilder")`.

Comment: since I have an existing XmlBuilder class. so I do this import * as mybuilder from 'xmlbuilder';  but I got "create' does not exist on type 'typeof  my existing XmlBuilder class  when I call mybuilder.create(..)

Comment: @SteveL You're trying to call a `create` method that is inside your XmlBuilder class. Check if you're not using `mybuilder` as a variable name. Maybe, try chaging `mybuilder` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are not recommended by many, and in this case it would make more sense for you to use a module definition.

This is written like:

```
declare module 'xmlbuilder' {
  // export types that describe the module here
}
```

Now when you import `xmlbuilder` it should automatically have the correct types (provided you have configured your tsconfig correctly).

You will need to define a path to your custom `typeRoots` (the directory for your type declarations) in your tsconfig.

Some more info about defining `typeRoots` can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

You can read more about the differences between namespaces and module declarations [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#pitfalls-of-namespaces-and-modules).